# Powershell does not show the virtualenv id or name?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, virtualenv, pipenv

When you run pipenv shell on VS Code powershell the virtualenv id does not show like

```
(virtualenv_name-JSHDF90KJH0)c:\
```

only shows

```
c:\
```

how do you setup powershell to show the virtualenv id or name in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

If you move to the Scripts folder you will find `Activate.ps1`:

```
Directory: D:\....\project_env\Scripts


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM           2030 activate
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM           1022 activate.bat
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM          19328 Activate.ps1
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM            368 deactivate.bat
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM         106417 easy_install-3.9.exe
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM         106417 easy_install.exe
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM         106408 pip.exe
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM         106408 pip3.9.exe
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM         106408 pip3.exe
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM         537264 python.exe
-a----         19-Jul-21   1:23 PM         535728 pythonw.exe
```

Run it to activate the environment in powershell...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a similar problem using **venv**, so I'll post what I did in my case.

I was using `python -m venv /app_env` or `app_env`/ and when I activated the enviroment, the name of the enviroment `(app_env)` wasn't showing.

But when I did

```
python -m venv app_env
```

And activated, It worked:

```
(budget_app_env) PS C:\Users\some_user\project\app_project>
```

So maybe you had a problem with "/"s.

And by the way, [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) recommends using **venv** because **pyenv** was *deprecated*.

Answer (score 0):

Once you `pipenv install` your project and ran `virtualenv -p python3 .`, you can run inside your project's folder the command

```
.\Scripts\activate
```

this will activate the virtual environment with the parentheses marks, indicating the name of which virtual environment is running:

```
(myproject) PS C:\Users\me\Dev\myproject>
```

This solution, however, won't show you the virtual environment ID, only it's name.